Duplicate step message when using ThreadExecutorJobLauncher
I need to start a couple of jobs in an iteration. The jobs are all restartable. This works fine when using the default JobLauncher with inline SyncTaskExecutor.
For example: 5 jobs and for every job I call jobLauncher.run(). This repeated multiple times.
Each job is using a JobParametersIncrementer to add a timestamp parameter.
Now I tried to lower the execution time by using an own defined TaskExecutorJobLauncher with an own ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. So jobs should be executed in parallel in one iteration. Copied from a post of Mahmoud Ben Hassine.
Unfortunately after the first execution of my jobs the result is that every step execution afterwards results in a "Duplicate step ... detected in execution of job ..." message.
Isn't it possible to restart jobs with a threaded job launcher?
Expected was that it works like before with the SyncTaskExecutor.
I tried to use the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor instead with no luck.
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutorJobLauncher taskExecutorJobLauncher(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor, JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

And the call is like
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
Set<JobExecution> executions = new HashSet<>();

jobs.forEach(job -> {
    try {
        log.info("Run job {}", job.getName());
        executions.add(taskExecutorJobLauncher.run(job, Objects.requireNonNull(job.getJobParametersIncrementer()).getNext(new JobParameters())));
    } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
});

while (executions.stream().anyMatch(JobExecution::isRunning)) {
    log.debug("#{} jobs are running", executions.stream().filter(JobExecution::isRunning).count());
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

}

This means you are NOT running different job instances in parallel. You did not share your setup, but I guess you need to start jobs with different identifying job parameters (at least one discriminating parameter).

I don't know if I understand your answer right @MahmoudBenHassine. So I added some code to my question. There is a incremented run.id on each job execution.

I guess the incrementers are returning the same value since they are called concurrently. You end up with the same job instances.

The incrementer is called manually on every taskExecutorJobLauncher.run(). I debugged it and the parameter run.id is everytime a different - and it is identifying

ok in that case I need to debug the case to investigate further. If you manage to assemble those code snippets with a pom.xml in a github repo  or a zip that I can clone/unzip and run, then i will try to take a look.
